# Determine all pairs $(x,y)$ of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Determine all pairs $(x,y)$ of integers such that 
>   $$1+2^{x}+2^{2x+1}=y^2.$$

I tried:
$$1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2$$
$$2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2-1$$
$$2^x+2^x2^x2=(y+1)(y-1)$$
$$2^x(1+ 2^{x+1})=(y+1)(y-1).$$

Comment: This is problem 4 of IMO 2006. You can check this: http://olympiads.win.tue.nl/imo/imo2006/solutions.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing the square gives

\begin{equation}
\left(2^{x+2}+1\right)^2=8y^2-7
\end{equation}

so $8y^2-7$ must be a perfect square of a number which is one more than four times a power of two. So two solutions are $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$.

Two more solutions are $(4,\pm23)$.

The steps to completing the square are as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
2\cdot2^{2x}+2^x&=&y^2-1\\
16\cdot2^{2x}+8\cdot2^x&=&8y^2-8\\
16\cdot2^{2x}+8\cdot2^x+1&=&8y^2-7\\
\left(4\cdot2^x+1\right)^2&=&8y^2-7\\
\left(2^{x+2}+1\right)^2&=&8y^2-7
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: how did you write the first step!?

Comment: I'll edit my answer to complete the square.

Comment: how is this "so 8y2−78y2−7 must be a perfect square of a number which is one more than four times a power of two. So two solutions are (0,2)(0,2) and (0,−2)(0,−2)."?

Comment: Yes, those two solutions were easily found from the original equation. But I had to use the completed square to find the solutions $(4,\pm23)$.

Comment: how did you find the first two solutions. I am having trouble with that.

Comment: In the original equation if you let $x=0$ you get $1+2^0+2^1=4=2^2=(-2)^2$ so you immediately get the two solutions $(0,\pm2)$ without completing the square.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56004/discussion-between-evariste-galois-and-john-wayland-bales).

Comment: isn't there any loss of generality in doing so?